# Why is counting items in pig so much slower than hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I have a set of data (~1TB) I imported in both Hive and Pig. Using our entire hadoop cluster but I have huge time differences where Hive is significantly faster than pig for just counting the number of records.

```
select count(*) from india_tab;
Time taken: 61.103 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

In PIG:

```
data = LOAD 'warehouse/india_tab/*' USING PigStorage()
     AS (ac_id:int, c_code01:chararray, longitude:float, latitude:float, satillite:chararray, month:chararray, day:chararray, timestamp:int, cm:int, li:double, tir:int,vis:int);
grpd = GROUP data ALL;
cnt = FOREACH grpd GENERATE COUNT(data);
DUMP cnt;
Runtime: 6m 9s
```

Answer (score 0):

Hive Uses only one reducer for the Count for full aggregate irrespective of input data size. if you want more efficiency then turn on the hive.map.aggr= true.

Pig sets the number of reducers using a heuristic based on the size of the input data.

## reducers = MIN (pig.exec.reducers.max, total input size (in bytes) / bytes per reducer)

generally by default reducer max is 999

ur total input size = 10^12 / 10^9

so for your pig job reducer =  999. that might be the reason for slowness compare to hive.

Use Parallel key word or set default_parallel to override the reducer num.

Comment: So I ran the tests again and pig runs this many 1111 mappers, 1 reducers, hive on the other hand is number of mappers: 406; number of reducers: 1

I'm not seeing exactly why Pig would use more, the PARALLEL docs says by default it is also 1, so it appears they are using the same number of reducers